# A fatal error has occurred Cannot write to cache directory /home/promozjo/tmp/horde Details have been logged for the administrator

Tags: email, cpanel, webmail

A fatal error has occurred
Cannot write to cache directory /home/promozjo/tmp/horde
Details have been logged for the administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Check as which user your web server runs, most probably it is `www-data`. Then issue

```
chown -R www-data:www-data  /home/promozjo/tmp/horde
```

Also a possible quick fix (but not recommended):

```
chmod -R 777 /home/promozjo/tmp/horde
```